# How to automatically flush appendonly.aof when using RDB+AOF mixed persistency in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use mixed persistency (RDB + AOF as tail) in Redis with the following configuration:

`aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
 appendonly yes
 save 10 1 # <-- just to speed the tests`

I assume from https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4.0/redis.conf#L746-L782 that when Redis is restarted, it loads the seed data from [RDB file][AOF tail].

I would like that every time the RDB is written, the AOF file would be flushed in order to keep in it only the tail (the latest updates since the last RDB saving).

Is this possible through some configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this isn't possible.

Despite the fact that AOF has an (optional, configuration-based) RDB preamble, the `save` directive controls only the RDB snapshotting (which can also be triggered with the `SAVE` or preferably `BGSAVE` commands).

To rewrite the AOF file, you'll need call [`BGAOFREWRITE`](https://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof) and/or tweak the 'auto-aof-rewrite-percentage' and 'auto-aof-rewrite-min-size' configuration directives.